# Initialization and release of global resources with spring

Tags: java, spring, initialization, resource-management

In our applications we usually have some resources (utilities) that are used application wide, for example that might be an apache `HttpClient`, or in my case `ConcurrencyUtils` which is an utility class that manages all the thread pools for `cpu` intensive and `io` tasks (adds some schedulers for reactive streams etc... a lot of custom stuff).

Now when I initialize my context trough spring i have to do something unnatural like this (in order to initialize and destroy static resource)

[image]

Note that `ConcurrencyUtil` is just a fake class with no use, we never use it but we use static methods of `ConcurrencyUtils` and this class only ensures that init and destroy are called (and i'm not sure how to ensure that destroy is called after all beans were destroyed)...

[image]

**So how do we run a piece of code before spring context creates any bean and after spring context has released all its beans (and is about to be reclaimable itself)?**

Whats the right way to initialize and release static resource with spring?

Comment: Please convert to images to text.

Comment: you cant see those? i thought images are better when people wont actually copy paste the code (when example is simple and alike)

Comment: I can see them. But what if someone wants to copy-paste your code in order to help you? Also we don't want to pollute this place with code-images.

Comment: Sure usually i do paste code, when its something one might want to copy to try, however this is rather simple example i don't think anyone will try to copy paste :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably works fine. You could also put this in one class that is in the classpath that gets scanned for beans:

```
@Configuration
public class ConcurrencyConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ConcurrencyUtil.init();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy(){
        ConcurrencyUtil.destroy();
    }
}
```

which looks a bit nicer I guess.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i wanted, i tought @PostConstruct will run after all beans are created but it actually runs before :)

Comment: it just runs after the containing bean has been created, so in this case, when ConcurrencyUtil was created.